# Desktop application in Java

Tags: java, desktop-application

I am new to Java and want to create a Desktop application in Java.
This application Reads and Writes different files.

Would someone please recomend me, what do i need for that and should I purchase a book or something else.

Thanks

Comment: Start with the [official tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

Comment: After that I would try searching for tutorials on what you want to know. There are literally thousands of them on even obscure topics. ;)

Comment: And make sure you have a good IDE like Netbeans or Eclipse or IntelliJ CE (all free)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> create a Desktop application in Java

Learn [Swing/awt/JFX](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

> This application Reads and Writes
>   different files.

Learn [File Operation in java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/fileOps.html)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using [NetBeans IDE](http://netbeans.org/) and follow its [tutorials](http://netbeans.org/kb/).  Its the easiest way to develop a Java Deskotp Application with a GUI.

Answer (score 2):

[Head First Java](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596004651) is a nice textbook. It gets you up and running very fast and it's even fun to read *gasp*

Answer (score 2):

After completing the basics and if you happen to use Eclipse IDE, hava a look at Google's [WindowBuilder Pro](http://www.eclipse.org/windowbuilder/). It is an Eclipse Plugin for quickly developing Swing Interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, most graphical interfaces are created using a framework called Swing. I suggest you take a look at Oracle's [Swing tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html) in order to get you easily started.